# vue js with vue router and lazy loading custom tags/components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'd like to have Vue custom components **loaded** only after the route has been clicked.

Let's say my app's stripped down html structure looks like this:

```
<div id="admin">
  <admin-menu><!-- component with routes --></admin-menu>
  <div id="content-container">
     <!-- want dynamically loaded Single Page Components here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like content container to be the target, where the dynamically loaded Single Page Components should be placed.

The one thing **I don't want** is to predefine the custom components in the content container right from the start like this:

```
<div id="admin">
  <admin-menu><!-- component with routes --></admin-menu>
  <div id="content-container">
     <my-component-1></my-component-1>
     <my-component-2></my-component-2>
     <my-component-3></my-component-3>
     <my-component-N></my-component-N>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I do that, they must be registered  i.e. loaded when vue hits them on startup of the app and but I'd like the components to be lazy loading.

So how can I initialize and place a single file component in the target content-container **only *after* the respective router link has been clicked**?